# VCF Card Support on mobile safari...or what should we use instead?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, vcf-vcard, microformats

Given a website made with jQuery Mobile, what's the "best way" (most-cross platform) to allow users to create a new contact with my company's address and phone number.  Vcard?